# How to scale proportionally to the parent?

Tags: html, css

I use an absolute div to put my centerbox into the `imgwrap`, but it don't follow the scale of my imgwrap box , even it is his parent.
How could I make the center box be center of the imgwrap and scale proportionally when user resize?
What's the correct way to do that?  I thought absolute would follow the parent

http://jsfiddle.net/gpqAx/

```
 <div id='imgwrap'>
            <img src='http://www.papercut.com/images/layout/banner-background-home-tree.png'>
        <div id='myabsolute'>
            <div id='centerbox'>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod             tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,             quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo             consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse             cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non             proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </div>
        </div>
</div> <!-- imgwrap -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're right but you also need to specify the distance from the edges. Add

```
top: 25%;
left: 25%;
right: 25%;
bottom: 25%;
```

to `#centerbox`

You might also need to adjust its height.
See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8bYDW/)

Comment: no, when you scale down it you will see the picture is not wrapping the box at all, it is not depend on its parent but the body.

Comment: `#centerbox` has to scale proportionally with the image, right? And it always has to be at the center? Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ddpfp/) other jsFiddle, here I've removed the `img` tag and set the image background to the outer `div`.

Comment: Yes but I don't want to stretch the background size, I want to keep the image in proportion, are there any way? That's why I used height:auto.